# CQRS aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, system-design

I'm new to the CQRS/ES world and I have a question. I'm working on an invoicing web application which uses event sourcing and CQRS.

My question is this - to my understanding, a new command coming into the system (let's say ChangeLineItemPrice) should pass through the domain model so it can be validated as a legal command (for example, to check if this line item actually exists, the price doesn't violate any business rules, etc). If all goes well (the command is not rejected) - then the appropriate event is created and stored (for example LineItemPriceChanged)

The thing I didn't quite get is how do I keep this aggregate in memory to begin with, before trying to apply the command. If I have a million invoices in the system, should I playback the whole history every time I want to apply a command? Do I always save the event without any validations and do the validations when constructing the view models / projections?

If I misunderstood any part of the process I would appreciate your feedback.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are not alone, this is a common misunderstanding. Let me answer the validation part first:

There are 2 types of validation which take place in this kind of system. The first is the kind where you look for valid email addresses, numeric only or required fields. This type is done before the command is even issued. A command which contains these sorts of problems should not be raised as commands (for belt and braces you can check at the domain side but this is not a domain concern and you are better off just preventing this scenario).

The next type of validation is when it **is** a domain concern. It could be the kind of thing you mention where you check prices are within a set of specified parameters. This is a domain concept the business people would understand, do and be able to articulate.

The next phase is for the domain to apply the state change and raise the associated events. These are then persisted and on success, published for the rest of the app.

All of this is can be done with the aggregate in memory. The actions are coordinated with a domain service which handles the command. It loads the aggregate, apply's all *it's* past events (or loads a snapshot) then issues the command. On success of the command it requests all the new uncommitted events and tries to persist them. On success it publishes the new events.

As you see it only loads the events for that specific aggregate. Even with a lot of events this process is lightning fast. If performance is a problem there are strategies such as keeping aggregates in memory or snapshotting which you can apply.

To your last point about validating events. As they can only be generated by your aggregate they are trustworthy.

If you want more detail check out my overview of CQRS and ES [here](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/). And take a look at my post about how to build aggregate roots [here](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/15/aggregate-root-cqrs-event-sourcing/).

Good luck - I hope they help!

Answer (score 1):

It is right that you have to replay the event to 'rehydrate' the domain aggregate. But you don't have to replay all events for all invoices. If you store the entity id of the root aggregate in the events, you can just select and replay the events that with the relevant id.

Then, how do you find the relevant aggregate root id? One of the read repositories should contain the relevant information to get the id, based on a set of search criteria.